# I have the below code I’m getting the error RelatedObjectDoesNotExist i

Tags: django, django-models

I have the below code I’m getting the error RelatedObjectDoesNotExistn Anyone can help me, please

Comment: Hi, your post does not contain any code.

Comment: Excuse me it is my first time that I use stakoverflow what I need is to add a class field (quantite)(value) with a (quantite_realisee) field from ProdArticle module. The result of this operation should populate another field (quantite_en_stock) in the class article. My code is below

Comment: You can edit your question and write the code